# How to create a vertical pull-up menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I'm trying to create a footer menu that pulls UP out of clicking on another part of the div that is in the parent div of both.

```
<div id="parent">
 <div id ="child-control">
  some content
 <div>
 <div id="child-slide">
  some content
 </div>
</div>
```

For the sliding actions I just hide the bottom div using the hidden setting. The parent div is just a full width of the webpage. So both children are 100% width as well.

```
<style>
#child-slide {
display: hidden;
height: 250px;
}
</style>
```

Here is the JS

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#child-control").click(function(){
   $("#child-slide").slideToggle("slow");
   });
 });
</script>
```

What ends up happening though is that when using a simple toggle jQuery function it does't really "slide up" but it opens up as in just pulls/rolls down to reveal the child-slide div. I'd rather it pull-up like the menu found at the bottom of this page - http://www.drexel.edu/ Not sure how to set things ups to do this though.

Comment: animate the bottom position

Comment: What they are doing there is much more complicated, you need to look at the the source code.

Comment: [Try this,](http://jsfiddle.net/mszots2n/) hope it helps.